# GAM vs spaMM for prediction, accounting for spatial autocorrelation

Tags: r, predictive-models, autocorrelation, spatial, generalized-additive-model

I'm modelling a species' response to environmental variables while controlling for spatial autocorrelation and temporal differences in sampling. The goal is to use this model for prediction.

I've been testing the predicitve power of various models by cross validation (train model with 80% of data, predictions on remainder). I initially tried using `gam()` from the `mgcv` package but found that the predictions weren't very accurate. I then tried using `fitme` from the `spaMM` package and found that this made more accurate predictions (code and example data below).

Why are the predictions from `gam` less accurate than `spaMM`? I wonder if I've misspecified the `gam` model? The diagnostic plots look fine for the `gam` model (less so for the `spaMM` model - code below). The only difference in these models is the smooth for the interaction between `week`, `lat` and `lon` - I don't know what the equivalent for this would be in the `spaMM` model (any ideas?).

Is it just that `spaMM` is a more appropriate approach with this data? My preference would be to use `gam` as I find the results easier to understand, although I'd be happy to use `spaMM` (or any other approach for that matter) if it gives better predictions (i.e. if the difference in predicitve power I've found is real and not due to errors in my approach).

Code:

```
    library(mgcv)
    library(spaMM)
    
    # function to calculate root mean squared error
    RMSE <- function(f, o){
      sqrt(mean((f - o)^2))
    }
    
    # set up training and validation sets
    set.seed(333)
    fold <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df)),size = floor(0.8*nrow(df)))
    train <- df[fold,]
    validate <- df[-fold,]
    
    # GAM
    m.gam <- gam(species_obs ~ 
                 + temp
                 + rainfall
                 + s(lat, lon, k = 50, m = c(1, 0.5))
                 + s(week, k = 7)
                 + ti(lat, lon, week, d = c(2,1), bs = c('ds'), m = list(c(1, 0.5), NA), k = c(20, 7))
                 + offset(log(duration))
                 , data = train, method = 'REML', family = nb)
    
    # predict
    pred.gam <- as.vector(predict(m.gam, validate))
    
    # inspect prediction vs actual
    data.frame(pred.gam, validate$species_obs)
plot(pred.gam ~ validate$species_obs)
    
    # calculate RMSE
    gam.rmse <- RMSE(f = pred.gam, o = validate$species_obs)
    
    
    # spaMM
    m.spamm <- fitme(species_obs ~ 
                            + temp
                            + rainfall
                            + week
                            + offset(log(duration))
                            + Matern(1|lat+lon)
                            , data=train, family=spaMM::negbin())
    
    # predict
    pred.spaMM <- as.vector(predict(m.spamm, validate))
    
    # inspect prediction vs actual
    data.frame(pred.spaMM, validate$species_obs)
plot(pred.spaMM ~ validate$species_obs)
    
    # calculate RMSE
    spaMM.rmse <- RMSE(f = pred.spaMM, o = validate$species_obs)
    
    # compare
    gam.rmse
    spaMM.rmse
    
    # diagnostic plots
    gratia::appraise(m.gam)
    simulationOutput <- DHARMa::simulateResiduals(m.spamm)
    plot(simulationOutput)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(398L, 425L, 311L, 66L, 295L, 316L, 2L, 
134L, 67L, 44L, 215L, 359L, 40L, 63L, 161L, 343L, 331L, 346L, 
415L, 326L, 349L, 78L, 228L, 431L, 123L, 406L, 420L, 272L, 419L, 
291L, 113L, 380L, 117L, 26L, 266L, 16L, 324L, 369L, 253L, 333L, 
409L, 265L, 309L, 160L, 109L, 363L, 169L, 105L, 147L, 184L, 204L, 
8L, 286L, 45L, 257L, 111L, 198L, 154L, 58L, 277L, 372L, 362L, 
410L, 385L, 175L, 61L, 304L, 34L, 102L, 149L, 301L, 255L, 407L, 
261L, 17L, 140L, 312L, 345L, 133L, 190L, 354L, 88L, 18L, 285L, 
15L, 314L, 207L, 397L, 336L, 239L, 163L, 315L, 86L, 402L, 387L, 
64L, 90L, 62L, 22L, 247L, 251L, 240L, 292L, 94L, 167L, 80L, 353L, 
394L, 75L, 323L, 427L, 322L, 244L, 356L, 214L, 104L, 373L, 367L, 
408L, 276L, 434L, 55L, 213L, 37L, 379L, 115L, 278L, 317L, 196L, 
5L, 327L, 243L, 318L, 211L, 237L, 186L, 335L, 51L, 32L, 106L, 
70L, 222L, 69L, 125L, 53L, 56L, 191L, 328L, 284L, 126L, 412L, 
1L, 185L, 82L, 194L, 334L, 170L, 360L, 400L, 437L, 224L, 281L, 
413L, 52L, 405L, 101L, 108L, 131L, 201L, 83L, 89L, 159L, 424L, 
216L, 249L, 65L, 283L, 174L, 260L, 57L, 47L, 435L, 297L, 432L, 
337L, 4L, 24L, 152L, 46L, 39L, 289L, 23L, 59L, 98L, 107L, 275L, 
258L, 221L, 296L, 81L, 294L, 195L, 176L, 245L, 230L, 389L, 54L, 
205L, 60L, 377L, 118L, 143L, 3L, 231L, 422L, 332L, 371L, 124L, 
274L, 384L, 130L, 302L, 202L, 13L, 310L, 421L, 110L, 138L, 173L, 
193L, 150L, 352L, 376L, 438L, 429L, 264L, 252L, 73L, 129L, 212L, 
279L, 341L, 430L, 43L, 411L, 181L, 232L, 338L, 114L, 401L), species_obs = c(16, 
5, 33, 3, 61, 7, 2, 4, 12, 72, 21, 25, 3, 31, 34, 59, 28, 381, 
34, 45, 149, 55, 34, 10, 3, 26, 2, 28, 2, 7, 44, 9, 14, 4, 60, 
4, 6, 8, 56, 118, 11, 80, 105, 119, 71, 0, 13, 34, 12, 48, 7, 
3, 133, 34, 8, 69, 127, 125, 7, 9, 50, 5, 9, 80, 11, 11, 51, 
13, 21, 67, 36, 153, 36, 12, 4, 31, 51, 75, 28, 22, 12, 5, 5, 
36, 16, 29, 6, 65, 10, 11, 2, 3, 11, 36, 10, 6, 30, 1, 19, 9, 
55, 9, 18, 16, 19, 18, 31, 388, 54, 5, 65, 39, 54, 5, 7, 14, 
98, 25, 115, 55, 15, 26, 22, 28, 17, 11, 62, 1, 87, 2, 19, 8, 
40, 2, 50, 21, 20, 6, 10, 41, 7, 56, 5, 6, 64, 16, 38, 1, 18, 
5, 8, 4, 48, 7, 66, 19, 7, 12, 21, 263, 22, 16, 14, 37, 39, 14, 
50, 8, 19, 20, 0, 61, 9, 72, 38, 1, 28, 5, 80, 103, 2, 27, 98, 
48, 11, 1, 10, 17, 29, 2, 146, 13, 12, 0, 3, 232, 12, 37, 51, 
29, 25, 38, 4, 42, 27, 18, 13, 7, 16, 15, 12, 35, 5, 14, 33, 
65, 5, 8, 25, 13, 2, 238, 4, 9, 38, 24, 32, 0, 17, 7, 7, 300, 
4, 430, 23, 93, 32, 37, 11, 3, 12, 26, 4, 7, 4, 30, 16, 28, 23, 
11), lat = c(51.451129, 51.502218, 51.489532, 51.495132, 51.511491, 
51.465341, 51.455139, 51.456529, 51.454777, 51.521703, 51.467293, 
51.487762, 51.475824, 51.503929, 51.498542, 51.505365, 51.496828, 
51.50229, 51.505993, 51.509689, 51.495543, 51.514119, 51.506038, 
51.482918, 51.448155, 51.472044, 51.44606, 51.495024, 51.523916, 
51.529513, 51.498967, 51.503607, 51.476284, 51.460305, 51.489773, 
51.516005, 51.460617, 51.492597, 51.505213, 51.454038, 51.502525, 
51.489721, 51.48483, 51.464065, 51.490967, 51.474593, 51.506125, 
51.468438, 51.486341, 51.502381, 51.465007, 51.523942, 51.501124, 
51.527381, 51.478232, 51.496083, 51.475137, 51.495459, 51.503625, 
51.461752, 51.529997, 51.476273, 51.503237, 51.496858, 51.505287, 
51.504638, 51.49083, 51.478764, 51.469812, 51.498601, 51.504588, 
51.504984, 51.472028, 51.503783, 51.507838, 51.476866, 51.489107, 
51.5039, 51.454272, 51.506429, 51.492034, 51.511654, 51.507251, 
51.477878, 51.511867, 51.488981, 51.45982, 51.499169, 51.455187, 
51.525597, 51.473402, 51.498695, 51.503315, 51.491199, 51.485027, 
51.475229, 51.50538, 51.504935, 51.501689, 51.496077, 51.505777, 
51.475398, 51.528991, 51.500417, 51.479416, 51.512185, 51.49177, 
51.504209, 51.480209, 51.46075, 51.490655, 51.477034, 51.500956, 
51.46164, 51.463871, 51.469704, 51.495696, 51.515154, 51.503549, 
51.469998, 51.483144, 51.495747, 51.480499, 51.487718, 51.504252, 
51.497831, 51.476197, 51.465557, 51.493491, 51.493815, 51.509747, 
51.451954, 51.480603, 51.456252, 51.518832, 51.501772, 51.489542, 
51.500988, 51.469842, 51.468268, 51.466462, 51.494986, 51.466056, 
51.478219, 51.49396, 51.502813, 51.506291, 51.447881, 51.477994, 
51.47869, 51.501041, 51.463646, 51.502, 51.526529, 51.511711, 
51.455286, 51.509251, 51.490036, 51.456044, 51.503862, 51.493901, 
51.457903, 51.505631, 51.509094, 51.497345, 51.468171, 51.491069, 
51.47711, 51.462577, 51.527362, 51.494216, 51.474142, 51.451633, 
51.471114, 51.4506, 51.461304, 51.473919, 51.50548, 51.502902, 
51.509742, 51.519995, 51.483867, 51.49833, 51.481017, 51.489147, 
51.448391, 51.459874, 51.503675, 51.527475, 51.475852, 51.502027, 
51.450253, 51.503561, 51.459049, 51.477071, 51.469962, 51.477865, 
51.48492, 51.51172, 51.510804, 51.520265, 51.497978, 51.461907, 
51.500177, 51.500548, 51.502364, 51.514178, 51.449365, 51.502786, 
51.517183, 51.475593, 51.47679, 51.453867, 51.500773, 51.521793, 
51.453182, 51.492361, 51.449356, 51.50472, 51.48996, 51.469197, 
51.49745, 51.474116, 51.514055, 51.48489, 51.521932, 51.484083, 
51.466515, 51.509177, 51.511645, 51.50507, 51.499093, 51.502571, 
51.50666, 51.494433, 51.495855, 51.502271, 51.46686, 51.469157, 
51.456329, 51.461621, 51.496366, 51.483239, 51.447783, 51.501109, 
51.499727, 51.516029, 51.496403, 51.499022, 51.48968), lon = c(17.32712, 
17.339485, 17.297313, 17.282313, 17.335249, 17.358213, 17.348407, 
17.36332, 17.317548, 17.360231, 17.308278, 17.295559, 17.382053, 
17.288016, 17.268009, 17.354437, 17.293116, 17.33772, 17.350742, 
17.29113, 17.319834, 17.346936, 17.329091, 17.290514, 17.342086, 
17.26711, 17.336913, 17.304416, 17.339454, 17.362003, 17.30583, 
17.384091, 17.293661, 17.286183, 17.320187, 17.308189, 17.356476, 
17.287544, 17.34188, 17.326814, 17.35231, 17.320066, 17.31377, 
17.368635, 17.311181, 17.278348, 17.290977, 17.303019, 17.305527, 
17.315307, 17.362876, 17.366789, 17.369126, 17.370542, 17.370688, 
17.325418, 17.359193, 17.322926, 17.314408, 17.366227, 17.364199, 
17.267791, 17.3518, 17.364918, 17.29854, 17.330414, 17.31632, 
17.29293, 17.303164, 17.310034, 17.326356, 17.331351, 17.267669, 
17.320875, 17.326238, 17.344633, 17.297602, 17.342287, 17.296472, 
17.325759, 17.316418, 17.293941, 17.325551, 17.375733, 17.341555, 
17.290418, 17.275607, 17.318046, 17.32659, 17.368091, 17.302578, 
17.385793, 17.366573, 17.313313, 17.375966, 17.340767, 17.293813, 
17.28353, 17.322853, 17.379632, 17.352715, 17.37553, 17.362152, 
17.2958, 17.274387, 17.347433, 17.31665, 17.335299, 17.301497, 
17.356474, 17.286939, 17.2657, 17.371728, 17.360524, 17.307898, 
17.303153, 17.301091, 17.345142, 17.391707, 17.369668, 17.312425, 
17.311435, 17.37221, 17.310367, 17.383809, 17.284236, 17.362692, 
17.358451, 17.285416, 17.389233, 17.290958, 17.319805, 17.334768, 
17.29626, 17.363543, 17.318716, 17.285766, 17.344752, 17.305798, 
17.303115, 17.310863, 17.314266, 17.310496, 17.282201, 17.301387, 
17.312488, 17.325604, 17.330627, 17.375799, 17.281866, 17.379533, 
17.345259, 17.31551, 17.356016, 17.30493, 17.325611, 17.291972, 
17.292673, 17.322426, 17.337843, 17.318787, 17.358639, 17.351146, 
17.345786, 17.2818, 17.298489, 17.311091, 17.379363, 17.355458, 
17.357466, 17.376965, 17.367449, 17.323354, 17.309375, 17.347163, 
17.356486, 17.369778, 17.298896, 17.320922, 17.332291, 17.350944, 
17.317929, 17.34012, 17.29532, 17.285625, 17.32001, 17.298458, 
17.317935, 17.370293, 17.382213, 17.374595, 17.29826, 17.31438, 
17.27979, 17.298206, 17.369555, 17.37049, 17.306157, 17.335395, 
17.3286, 17.363004, 17.272818, 17.283137, 17.37245, 17.288305, 
17.343277, 17.321669, 17.340615, 17.312236, 17.380145, 17.294091, 
17.345046, 17.336208, 17.28809, 17.350793, 17.326817, 17.287156, 
17.345781, 17.35423, 17.389642, 17.28138, 17.317021, 17.274507, 
17.340184, 17.3138, 17.351766, 17.302942, 17.357397, 17.297564, 
17.304735, 17.318904, 17.317477, 17.291807, 17.33538, 17.287692, 
17.304503, 17.35348, 17.302022, 17.281458, 17.296259, 17.366458, 
17.368954, 17.292115, 17.292487, 17.379349, 17.312119, 17.301971, 
17.362325, 17.305982, 17.312158), duration = c(70.1355555555555, 
50.7836111111112, 121.600833333333, 84.4341666666667, 66.2302777777778, 
63.9608333333333, 75.6888888888888, 67.15, 59.9852777777778, 
72.9563888888888, 72.4122222222222, 61.8591666666667, 72.9563888888888, 
96.7561111111112, 75.4586111111112, 82.2433333333333, 54.6652777777778, 
63.5977777777778, 50.7836111111112, 73.3108333333333, 63.5977777777778, 
70.2347222222222, 40.7666666666667, 41.1544444444445, 67.15, 
51.0241666666667, 50.7836111111112, 47.5847222222222, 59.3911111111112, 
76.3677777777778, 67.5336111111112, 61.5280555555555, 67.5336111111112, 
87.6202777777778, 69.0416666666667, 75.2983333333333, 63.9608333333333, 
61.5280555555555, 59.3541666666667, 54.6652777777778, 50.7836111111112, 
69.0416666666667, 66.2302777777778, 64.8672222222222, 69.4605555555555, 
43.9444444444445, 75.4586111111112, 81.2630555555555, 78.1188888888888, 
75.0188888888888, 83.0036111111112, 75.2983333333333, 66.6222222222222, 
48.3775, 69.455, 93.1305555555555, 83.0036111111112, 78.1188888888888, 
84.8886111111112, 37.7319444444445, 52.5955555555555, 52.8769444444445, 
50.7836111111112, 61.2030555555555, 75.4586111111112, 84.8886111111112, 
66.2302777777778, 87.6202777777778, 69.4605555555555, 78.1188888888888, 
66.2302777777778, 59.3541666666667, 51.0241666666667, 69.0416666666667, 
75.2983333333333, 78.5658333333333, 121.600833333333, 63.5977777777778, 
67.15, 75.0188888888888, 45.1677777777778, 69.8472222222222, 
75.2983333333333, 56.9347222222222, 75.2983333333333, 83.1941666666667, 
72.4122222222222, 61.2030555555555, 63.9608333333333, 69.8705555555555, 
75.4586111111112, 63.9608333333333, 93.6469444444445, 61.2030555555555, 
70.1355555555555, 109.143055555556, 69.8472222222222, 96.7561111111112, 
75.2983333333333, 69.455, 59.3541666666667, 69.455, 76.3677777777778, 
81.7147222222222, 75.4586111111112, 70.2347222222222, 63.5977777777778, 
61.2030555555555, 84.4341666666667, 63.9608333333333, 67.7219444444445, 
73.3108333333333, 69.455, 52.8769444444445, 72.4122222222222, 
81.2630555555555, 61.5280555555555, 52.5955555555555, 59.3911111111112, 
96.0336111111112, 41.1544444444445, 72.5666666666667, 83.0036111111112, 
87.6202777777778, 61.5280555555555, 67.5336111111112, 37.7319444444445, 
63.9608333333333, 62.2511111111112, 75.6888888888888, 63.9608333333333, 
69.455, 63.9608333333333, 72.4122222222222, 59.7094444444445, 
75.0188888888888, 73.3108333333333, 84.8886111111112, 87.6202777777778, 
81.2630555555555, 84.4341666666667, 82.5130555555555, 84.4341666666667, 
55.7986111111112, 72.5666666666667, 84.8886111111112, 75.0188888888888, 
63.9608333333333, 66.6222222222222, 67.15, 59.3911111111112, 
75.6888888888888, 75.0188888888888, 81.7147222222222, 62.2511111111112, 
63.9608333333333, 75.4586111111112, 61.8591666666667, 43.4841666666667, 
41.1544444444445, 82.5130555555555, 66.6222222222222, 50.7836111111112, 
84.8886111111112, 51.0241666666667, 81.2630555555555, 93.1305555555555, 
78.5658333333333, 83.0036111111112, 81.7147222222222, 93.6469444444445, 
42.9927777777778, 50.7836111111112, 72.4122222222222, 69.455, 
109.143055555556, 66.6222222222222, 53.5841666666667, 69.0416666666667, 
84.8886111111112, 84.8886111111112, 41.1544444444445, 75.9177777777778, 
41.1544444444445, 73.3108333333333, 75.6888888888888, 87.6202777777778, 
66.7675, 72.9563888888888, 85.3433333333333, 66.6222222222222, 
87.6202777777778, 84.8886111111112, 81.2630555555555, 81.2630555555555, 
105.955, 69.455, 93.1044444444445, 66.2302777777778, 70.2347222222222, 
76.3677777777778, 62.2511111111112, 75.4586111111112, 69.455, 
69.8705555555555, 61.2030555555555, 84.8886111111112, 83.0036111111112, 
84.8886111111112, 61.5280555555555, 67.5336111111112, 67.15, 
75.6888888888888, 59.7094444444445, 59.3911111111112, 63.9608333333333, 
61.5280555555555, 55.7986111111112, 57.2722222222222, 70.1355555555555, 
67.15, 66.2302777777778, 72.4122222222222, 75.2983333333333, 
66.2302777777778, 59.3911111111112, 81.2630555555555, 78.5658333333333, 
75.4586111111112, 72.8425, 78.1188888888888, 63.5977777777778, 
61.5280555555555, 41.1544444444445, 67.7219444444445, 69.0416666666667, 
59.3541666666667, 84.4341666666667, 67.15, 72.4122222222222, 
66.6222222222222, 72.8933333333333, 41.1544444444445, 60.6344444444445, 
59.3911111111112, 75.0188888888888, 69.8705555555555, 72.8933333333333, 
67.5336111111112, 61.2030555555555), week = c(3, 2, 4, 11, 5, 
4, 12, 9, 11, 11, 7, 3, 11, 11, 8, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 10, 7, 1, 
9, 2, 2, 5, 2, 5, 9, 3, 9, 12, 6, 12, 4, 3, 6, 4, 2, 6, 5, 8, 
10, 3, 8, 10, 9, 8, 7, 12, 5, 11, 6, 10, 7, 9, 11, 5, 3, 3, 2, 
3, 8, 11, 5, 12, 10, 9, 5, 6, 2, 6, 12, 9, 4, 4, 9, 8, 4, 10, 
12, 5, 12, 4, 7, 3, 4, 6, 8, 4, 10, 3, 3, 11, 10, 11, 12, 6, 
6, 6, 5, 10, 8, 10, 4, 3, 11, 4, 2, 4, 6, 3, 7, 10, 3, 3, 2, 
5, 1, 11, 7, 12, 3, 9, 5, 4, 7, 12, 4, 6, 4, 7, 6, 8, 4, 11, 
12, 10, 11, 7, 11, 9, 11, 11, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 12, 8, 10, 7, 4, 
8, 3, 3, 1, 7, 5, 2, 11, 2, 10, 10, 9, 7, 10, 10, 8, 2, 7, 6, 
11, 5, 8, 6, 11, 11, 1, 5, 1, 4, 12, 12, 9, 11, 11, 5, 12, 11, 
10, 10, 5, 6, 7, 5, 10, 5, 7, 8, 6, 6, 3, 11, 7, 11, 3, 9, 9, 
12, 6, 2, 4, 3, 9, 5, 3, 9, 5, 7, 12, 5, 2, 10, 9, 8, 7, 9, 4, 
3, 1, 2, 6, 6, 11, 9, 7, 5, 4, 1, 11, 2, 8, 6, 4, 9, 3), temp = structure(c(0.379862311883938, 
-0.0590348398838672, 0.93156013349855, -0.388207703709687, 1.4277454730557, 
0.295383582949186, -2.08944689712732, -0.662005693247078, -0.0939005014728701, 
-0.477422778952212, 0.666991289675932, 0.516248576335129, -0.563561472289814, 
-0.806937462989702, -0.485113733714489, 0.177159809775178, 0.116934205077238, 
-0.0220549197503717, 0.113242546791336, 0.307397432366173, -0.0220549197503717, 
-0.23131222655907, 1.02877380169386, -0.305145392277009, -0.108256950362482, 
-0.169784588460759, -0.00981272940521774, 1.75808140528556, 0.699293299677533, 
1.37524276822956, -0.98194941135816, 0.354738526327126, -0.23131222655907, 
-2.24018961046812, 1.35610083637674, -1.74489212377691, 0.295383582949186, 
0.473179229666329, 1.60221138876989, 0.116934205077238, 0.0886314915520457, 
1.56068023305355, 1.4277454730557, -0.194395643700083, -0.243617754178698, 
-0.00489051835735971, -0.635856447055291, -0.58201976371929, 
0.365505862994327, -1.1526886070809, 0.389433277810312, -2.23711322856321, 
1.4802770246745, 0.0640204363127213, 0.946942043023137, -0.165682745920894, 
0.494713903000729, 0.182461139651923, -0.614321773720891, 1.31691315981737, 
-0.0344237846445428, 0.23193401403373, 0.37165862680414, 0.0640204363127213, 
-1.0880845870777, -0.926574537069696, 1.4277454730557, -1.68028810377371, 
-0.883505190400896, -0.215930317034484, 1.19459078636874, 1.29457319827847, 
-0.132868005601806, 1.17305611303434, -2.53244589143498, -1.0019458937401, 
1.09153199255413, -0.0220549197503717, 0.0640204363127213, -1.1203865970793, 
-0.00289187547271968, -1.26497654661027, -2.75394538858882, 1.66373902686816, 
-2.45861272571704, 0.54639711900329, 0.936174706355937, 0.430109882997528, 
0.295383582949186, 0.979244053024738, -0.678925793724092, 0.295383582949186, 
-0.127398882215297, 0.623921943007131, 0.216638434350237, -0.599247502386811, 
-0.93272730087951, -0.854792292621707, -2.24941875618286, 1.03308073636074, 
1.29457319827847, 0.914640033021536, 1.51091629793462, -0.786599160396094, 
-0.754297150394493, -0.378978557994949, -0.0220549197503717, 
0.294936035774541, -0.129791623696882, 0.295383582949186, 0.0257365726071244, 
0.307397432366173, 0.850036013018335, 0.23193401403373, 0.925407369688737, 
-1.0234805670745, 0.333203852992726, 0.445491792522114, 0.333203852992726, 
1.54403980365877, -0.194395643700083, -0.280534337037685, 0.46600100522154, 
-2.05714488712572, 0.272911938046161, -0.169784588460759, 1.31691315981737, 
0.295383582949186, 0.740824455393871, -1.69567001329828, 0.295383582949186, 
1.45300686638155, 0.295383582949186, 0.591619933005531, 1.1961289773212, 
-1.1957579537497, 0.307397432366173, -0.754297150394493, -1.88486750045051, 
-0.754297150394493, -0.205162980367284, 0.753129983013534, -0.0436529303592806, 
-0.811722945952906, -0.600478055148767, -0.926574537069696, -1.2065252904169, 
0.295383582949186, 1.4802770246745, -0.0836458951231574, -0.0436529303592806, 
-1.7202810685376, -0.969643883738497, -0.398975040376887, 0.740824455393871, 
0.295383582949186, -0.851203180399295, 0.343741969047418, 0.896694471909548, 
-0.489728306571875, 0.944549301541552, 1.4802770246745, 0.0886314915520457, 
-0.797366497063294, -0.0836458951231574, -1.3249659937561, -0.280534337037685, 
-0.711227803725692, 0.79141384671913, -0.463579060380088, 0.433186264902452, 
-1.57261473710171, 0.00249279821444417, 0.731595309679133, 1.14075410303274, 
-0.831821974398335, 1.4802770246745, -0.481524621492077, 1.67912093639275, 
-0.948109210404097, -0.818901170397695, -0.120562477982144, 1.5207151440021, 
-0.0344237846445428, 0.307397432366173, -2.05253031426834, -2.26172428380252, 
-0.0836458951231574, -0.723533331345355, -1.0988519237449, 1.4802770246745, 
-2.01407554045692, -0.754297150394493, -0.495881070381689, -0.334371020373686, 
1.34892261193196, 1.06538274636234, 0.590423562264738, 1.15152143969994, 
-0.403589613234273, 1.51091629793462, 0.986935007787013, -0.463579060380088, 
0.796199329682334, 1.01154606302634, -0.162093633698483, -0.700460467058492, 
0.772271914866349, -1.0127132304073, 0.440877219664728, -0.735838858965017, 
-0.194395643700083, -1.8064197618752, 1.07307370112461, -0.495881070381689, 
0.295383582949186, 0.272911938046161, -0.811722945952906, 1.47109813847757, 
0.216638434350237, -0.526644889430827, 1.38840284637834, 0.634689279674331, 
-2.5570569466743, 1.4277454730557, 0.0317184263111207, -0.0544202670264808, 
-0.0974896136952816, -0.829668507064895, 0.796199329682334, -0.215930317034484, 
-0.0220549197503717, 0.333203852992726, -0.120562477982144, -0.098685984436074, 
1.57144756972075, 1.22074003256053, -0.302069010372085, -0.46511725133255, 
0.623921943007131, 1.4802770246745, 0.152009985561075, -0.342061975135962, 
0.0353075385335322, 0.0424857629783209, -0.345138357040886, 1.54991289638635, 
0.152009985561075, -0.920421773259883, 0.322436516325526), .Dim = c(250L, 
1L)), rainfall = structure(c(-0.42221818637359, 0.32243062926338, 
-0.541893888886675, -0.724731767726109, -0.352407359907624, -0.77127231870342, 
-0.26265058302281, -0.741353393075149, -0.794542594192075, -0.661569591399759, 
2.16078239286715, -0.375677635396279, -0.661569591399759, -0.691119147575829, 
0.997268618434384, -0.775926373801151, -0.794542594192075, -0.794542594192075, 
0.32243062926338, -0.773857904868826, -0.794542594192075, -0.688164191958222, 
1.29047408959144, -0.289245183581274, -0.741353393075149, 0.32243062926338, 
0.32243062926338, -0.236055982464348, 0.182808976331448, -0.236055982464348, 
-0.741353393075149, -0.375677635396279, -0.741353393075149, -0.42221818637359, 
0.997268618434384, -0.448812786932054, -0.77127231870342, -0.375677635396279, 
0.774538838757258, -0.794542594192075, 0.32243062926338, 0.997268618434384, 
-0.352407359907624, 1.01389024378342, -0.688164191958222, -0.236055982464348, 
0.997268618434384, -0.701461492237454, -0.748002043214764, 1.04380916941169, 
3.23897182384151, -0.448812786932054, -0.352407359907624, -0.794542594192075, 
0.578403659638588, -0.711803836899078, 3.23897182384151, -0.748002043214764, 
-0.678191216748798, -0.757310153410226, -0.315839784139738, -0.315839784139738, 
0.32243062926338, -0.375677635396279, 0.997268618434384, -0.678191216748798, 
-0.352407359907624, -0.42221818637359, -0.688164191958222, -0.748002043214764, 
-0.352407359907624, 0.774538838757258, 0.32243062926338, 0.997268618434384, 
-0.448812786932054, -0.748002043214764, -0.541893888886675, -0.794542594192075, 
-0.741353393075149, 1.04380916941169, -0.794542594192075, -0.688164191958222, 
-0.448812786932054, -0.289245183581274, -0.448812786932054, -0.775926373801151, 
2.16078239286715, -0.375677635396279, -0.77127231870342, 0.857646965502452, 
0.997268618434384, -0.77127231870342, -0.711803836899078, -0.375677635396279, 
-0.42221818637359, -0.701461492237454, -0.688164191958222, -0.691119147575829, 
-0.448812786932054, 0.578403659638588, 0.774538838757258, 0.578403659638588, 
-0.236055982464348, -0.701461492237454, 0.997268618434384, -0.688164191958222, 
-0.794542594192075, -0.375677635396279, -0.724731767726109, -0.77127231870342, 
0.0742143573843895, -0.773857904868826, 0.578403659638588, -0.315839784139738, 
2.16078239286715, -0.701461492237454, -0.375677635396279, -0.315839784139738, 
0.182808976331448, 0.0178015683209832, -0.289245183581274, -0.714758792516685, 
3.23897182384151, -0.42221818637359, -0.375677635396279, -0.741353393075149, 
-0.757310153410226, -0.77127231870342, 2.58297167673275, -0.26265058302281, 
-0.77127231870342, 0.578403659638588, -0.77127231870342, 2.16078239286715, 
0.774538838757258, 1.04380916941169, -0.773857904868826, -0.678191216748798, 
-0.42221818637359, -0.701461492237454, -0.724731767726109, 2.10131391106281, 
-0.724731767726109, -0.732488526222328, -0.714758792516685, -0.678191216748798, 
1.04380916941169, -0.77127231870342, -0.352407359907624, -0.741353393075149, 
0.182808976331448, -0.26265058302281, 1.04380916941169, -0.701461492237454, 
2.58297167673275, -0.77127231870342, 0.997268618434384, -0.375677635396279, 
-0.236055982464348, -0.289245183581274, 2.10131391106281, -0.352407359907624, 
0.32243062926338, -0.678191216748798, 0.32243062926338, -0.701461492237454, 
-0.711803836899078, -0.748002043214764, 3.23897182384151, -0.701461492237454, 
-0.711803836899078, 1.73726337897362, 0.32243062926338, 2.16078239286715, 
0.578403659638588, -0.701461492237454, -0.352407359907624, 1.59453902264321, 
0.997268618434384, -0.678191216748798, -0.678191216748798, -0.289245183581274, 
-0.401533497050341, -0.289245183581274, -0.773857904868826, -0.26265058302281, 
-0.42221818637359, -0.741353393075149, -0.661569591399759, -0.678191216748798, 
-0.352407359907624, -0.42221818637359, -0.678191216748798, -0.701461492237454, 
-0.701461492237454, 0.213836010316318, 0.578403659638588, 3.07763124712017, 
-0.352407359907624, -0.688164191958222, -0.236055982464348, 2.58297167673275, 
0.997268618434384, 0.578403659638588, 0.857646965502452, -0.375677635396279, 
-0.678191216748798, 3.23897182384151, -0.678191216748798, -0.375677635396279, 
-0.741353393075149, -0.741353393075149, -0.26265058302281, 0.774538838757258, 
0.182808976331448, -0.77127231870342, -0.375677635396279, -0.732488526222328, 
-0.315839784139738, -0.42221818637359, -0.741353393075149, -0.352407359907624, 
2.16078239286715, -0.448812786932054, -0.352407359907624, 0.182808976331448, 
-0.701461492237454, -0.748002043214764, 0.997268618434384, 3.74316112609571, 
-0.748002043214764, -0.794542594192075, -0.375677635396279, -0.289245183581274, 
0.0742143573843895, 0.997268618434384, 0.774538838757258, -0.724731767726109, 
-0.741353393075149, 2.16078239286715, -0.352407359907624, -0.773857904868826, 
-0.289245183581274, -0.701461492237454, 0.182808976331448, 1.04380916941169, 
0.857646965502452, -0.773857904868826, -0.741353393075149, -0.375677635396279
), .Dim = c(250L, 1L))), row.names = c(427L, 455L, 339L, 74L, 
321L, 344L, 2L, 146L, 75L, 51L, 235L, 388L, 47L, 71L, 173L, 372L, 
359L, 375L, 445L, 354L, 378L, 87L, 250L, 462L, 134L, 436L, 450L, 
298L, 449L, 317L, 123L, 409L, 127L, 31L, 292L, 17L, 352L, 398L, 
279L, 361L, 439L, 291L, 337L, 172L, 119L, 392L, 183L, 115L, 159L, 
201L, 222L, 8L, 312L, 52L, 283L, 121L, 216L, 166L, 65L, 303L, 
401L, 391L, 440L, 414L, 190L, 69L, 332L, 40L, 112L, 161L, 328L, 
281L, 437L, 287L, 18L, 152L, 340L, 374L, 145L, 207L, 383L, 98L, 
19L, 311L, 16L, 342L, 225L, 426L, 364L, 263L, 175L, 343L, 96L, 
432L, 416L, 72L, 100L, 70L, 23L, 273L, 277L, 265L, 318L, 104L, 
180L, 89L, 382L, 423L, 83L, 351L, 457L, 350L, 269L, 385L, 232L, 
114L, 402L, 396L, 438L, 302L, 465L, 62L, 231L, 44L, 408L, 125L, 
304L, 345L, 214L, 5L, 355L, 268L, 346L, 229L, 261L, 203L, 363L, 
58L, 38L, 116L, 78L, 243L, 77L, 137L, 60L, 63L, 208L, 356L, 310L, 
138L, 442L, 1L, 202L, 92L, 211L, 362L, 184L, 389L, 430L, 468L, 
245L, 307L, 443L, 59L, 435L, 111L, 118L, 143L, 219L, 93L, 99L, 
171L, 454L, 237L, 275L, 73L, 309L, 189L, 286L, 64L, 54L, 466L, 
323L, 463L, 365L, 4L, 29L, 164L, 53L, 46L, 315L, 26L, 66L, 108L, 
117L, 301L, 284L, 242L, 322L, 90L, 320L, 213L, 191L, 270L, 253L, 
418L, 61L, 223L, 68L, 406L, 128L, 155L, 3L, 254L, 452L, 360L, 
400L, 135L, 300L, 413L, 142L, 330L, 220L, 14L, 338L, 451L, 120L, 
150L, 188L, 210L, 162L, 381L, 405L, 469L, 460L, 290L, 278L, 81L, 
141L, 230L, 305L, 369L, 461L, 50L, 441L, 197L, 255L, 366L, 124L, 
431L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You're not comparing like with like; you have smooth of `week` in one model but linear in the other, a smooth interaction between space and `week` in one and no interaction at all in the other, you're assuming the spatial effect is smooth in one and likely rough in the other. Try fitting the same model in *mgcv* (as you did in the *spaMM* one) and crank `k` as high as it can go. Did you miss a `bs = 'ds'` on the first spatial smooth? I suspect the Matern gets a short estimated length scale & hence is very rough, esp as you have simple fixed effs compared to the GAM, whereas...

Comment: In the GAM you're assuming space is essentially smooth (and flat away from the data given the Duchon spline settings).

Comment: Also, I suspect you're comparing results from the GAM on the link scale with the response scale in spaMM. The default for `predict.gam()` is `type = "link"`, but for models fitted by `fitme()`, the default is `type = "response"`. Regardless, your comparison of the GAM predictions to the observed data makes no sense as you are comparing observed counts with link-scale (i.e. log-scale) predictions from the model.

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson. I'm aware that the models weren't exactly the same (I haven't worked out how to specify the interaction with week and location in the spaMM model). The issue was the prediction scale: `type = "response"` has fixed it - I hadn't spotted that the default in `gam` was `link`. If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it. Thank again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple fix - as pointed out by @GavinSimpson, the issue was the prediction scale: changing the GAM prediction to type = "response" has fixed it. Both approaches now perform similarly.